# Multiple dimension array into dojo datagrid

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I need to create a dojo datagrid with values populated from a JSON file, I've managed to get the initial values in, however the data contains arrays of arrays, and I'm not sure how to get the data from the next array to show.

Here's a jsfiddle showing the data http://jsfiddle.net/bqK2a/2/

This is the structure of my grid, the problem is that "MetricData" just shows [object Object]

```
grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
    store: store,
    query: {DataDTS:"*"},
     structure: [
    { name: "DateDTS", field: "DataDTS", width: "10%" },
    { name: "Small", field: "System", width: "10%" },
    { name: "SourceServer", field: "SourceServer", width: "10%" },
    { name: "OldestData", field: "OldestData", width: "10%" },
    { name: "MetricData", field: "MetricData", width: "10%" },

]
},"gridDiv");
```

I will then need to display the data in columns where headers are grouped, is there a way to do this with the datagrid? For example, in the data, for Them, each of the sections will need to be grouped and shown under the Them heading.

THEM

++++++++

1|2|3|4

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the grid is just going to call toString on the value in the MetricData property of the object and will have no clue as to how you want it to display the values underneath MetricData.

What it looks like you're looking for is a formatter which is well enough described here:
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/populating_datagrid/

You would use a formatter property on your column and have that function return whatever content from MetricData you want in the cell.

I probably totally missed your were saying about the 'THEM' and formatting stuff at the bottom, but this will fix your only getting [object Object] problem.